Azure DevOps build pipeline is no longer able to build
The pipeline yaml has not changed and now it fails when trying to restore and build the solution.
This is the logged error:

The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and error(System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> NuGet.CommandLine.CommandLineException: Error parsing solution file at C:\agent_work\1\s\Accuro3S.Algorithms.sln: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. at NuGet.CommandLine.MsBuildUtility.GetAllProjectFileNamesWithMsBuild(String solutionFile, String msbuildPath) at NuGet.CommandLine.RestoreCommand.ProcessSolutionFile(String solutionFileFullPath, PackageRestoreInputs restoreInputs) at NuGet.CommandLine.RestoreCommand.d__37.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at NuGet.CommandLine.RestoreCommand.d__30.MoveNext() --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions) at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at NuGet.CommandLine.Command.Execute() at NuGet.CommandLine.Program.MainCore(String workingDirectory, String[] args) ---> (Inner Exception #0) NuGet.CommandLine.CommandLineException: Error parsing solution file at C:\agent_work\1\s\Accuro3S.Algorithms.sln: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. at NuGet.CommandLine.MsBuildUtility.GetAllProjectFileNamesWithMsBuild(String solutionFile, String msbuildPath) at NuGet.CommandLine.RestoreCommand.ProcessSolutionFile(String solutionFileFullPath, PackageRestoreInputs restoreInputs) at NuGet.CommandLine.RestoreCommand.d__37.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at NuGet.CommandLine.RestoreCommand.d__30.MoveNext()<---)

I've confirmed that there's nothing wrong with Accuro3S.Algorithms.sln.
Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.
I tried creating a new Personal Access token.
I tried running a manual restore of the .sln on my build agent machine and it ran successfully.

Even if the pipeline hasn't changed, other things might have changed: source code, build agents (and installed tools), new versions of the nuget packages being downloaded, etc. Or sometimes temporary issues (nuget outage, networking issues) might prevent buget packages from being downloaded and restored.

Agree with Rui. Please check if there are other changes in your project. You can compare the successful log and the failed log to check if there are more difference. If possible, can you please  share a Minimal, Reproducible code example  to better troubleshooting the issue?

The fix was to download nuget.exe version 6.6.1.2 to C:\agent_work_tool\NuGet\4.1.0\x64\ but it's not clear to me why I would need to do that. Do you know?

Hi @ajhawald, I shared some details in the answer. By the way, it seems Is there a typo in your nuget.exe version 6.6.1.2? It seems that there is no nuget.exe version 6.6.1.2. When I enter versionSpec: 6.1.2 in the NuGetToolInstaller@1 task, the pipeline error message tells me that the available 6.x versions are: 6.11.1; 6.11.0; 6.10.2; 6.10.1; 6.9.1; 6.8.1; 6.8.0; 6.7.1; 6.7.0; 6.6.2; 6.6.1; 6.5.1; 6.5.0; 6.4.3; 6.4.2; 6.4.0; 6.3.4; 6.3.3; 6.3.1; 6.3.0; 6.2.4; 6.2.2; 6.2.1; 6.2.0; 6.1.0; 6.0.6; 6.0.5; 6.0.3; 6.0.2; 6.0.0;

The error message indicates a problem with parsing the solution file, but you've confirmed that the solution file itself is not the issue. The fix you mentioned, downloading a specific version of nuget.exe, seems to have resolved the problem, but you're unsure why this step was necessary.
You can check the NuGet Release Notes to learn what is fixed in this version. For example, certain versions of nuget.exe might have fixes or improvements that are necessary for your particular setup or environment. In your case, the version might have addressed a specific issue that was causing the error during the restore process. You can check if there are any relevant changes in your code that require a new version of nuget.exe.
In the pipeline, you can use the NuGetToolInstaller@1 task to install a specific version of nuget.exe before using the nuget restore task.
# NuGet tool installer v1
# Acquires a specific version of NuGet from the internet or the tools cache and adds it to the PATH. Use this task to change the version of NuGet used in the NuGet tasks.
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '6.x' # string. Version of NuGet.exe to install. 
    checkLatest: false # boolean. Always check for new versions. Default: false.


Hi @ajhawald, glad to help you. If you have more question about the issue, just let me know.
